# get trouble when using python pandas export data to csv

Tags: python, pandas

```
    ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-24-c4da7a3d2c81> in <module>()
         58             result.append(g.contents[0]+'--dates')
         59 
    ---> 60         sample_df.loc[num] = result
         61         sample_df.to_csv("Final_v1.0.csv", columns=clns)
         62 

error: cannot set a row with mismatched columns
```

Here is part of my code:

```
clns = ['Company','Title','Location','Dates','Company2','Title2','Location2','Dates2']
sample_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = clns)
num = (len(sample_df)+1)
...
sample_df.loc[num] = result
sample_df.to_csv("Final_v1.0.csv", columns=clns)
```

this is the contents of the *result*

```
[u'CVS, Richardson--company name', u'Java Developer--title', '-Not Provided--location', u'August 2017 to December 2017--dates', u'StrikeTru--company name', u'Java Developer--title', u'Hyderabad, Telangana--location', u'May 2012 to July 2015--dates']
```

I set up 8 columns and there are 8 contents in the *result* why I still get mismatched error?

Comment: For example, `sample_df.loc[num, :] = result` will work as long as result is a list with the same number of items as the number of columns in `sample_df`.

Comment: result is an array, i already posted it

Comment: Both methods work. Please check the length of `result`, it should be 8 for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Double check the value in `sample_df.columns` before assignment. You can use a `print` statement or `import pdb; pdb.set_trace();` to open an interactive shell where you can examine variable values. I think you'll find that, somewhere along the line, you've accidentally added a column, which is causing the mismatch.

Here's a minimal version of the example code you provided I used to recreate this problem:

```
import pandas as pd

clns = [
    'Company','Title','Location','Dates',
    'Company2','Title2','Location2','Dates2',
]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = clns)

row = [
    'CVS, Richardson--company name', 'Java Developer--title',
    '-Not Provided--location', 'August 2017 to December 2017--dates',
    'StrikeTru--company name', 'Java Developer--title',
    'Hyderabad, Telangana--location', 'May 2012 to July 2015--dates',
]
# Works fine!  Length of `row` matches length of `df.columns`
df.loc[0] = row

# Accidentally cause a column to be created by indexing a non-existent column.
# Note that 'New Column' doesn't have to be a string, it could be a number as well.
df.loc[(0, 'New Column')] = None

# Indexing 'New Column' automatically created it
print(df.columns)
# Index(['Company', 'Title', 'Location', 'Dates', 'Company2', 'Title2',
# 'Location2', 'Dates2', 'New Column'],
# dtype='object')

# Setting a row now fails with
df.loc[1] = row
# ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns
```